# Symfony2 search form field, parameters in URL

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am working on a search form which will be querying a database for product details. For each query, I want to show the params in the URL. I don't know how to do it in Symfony2, in plain old PHP I could just use `method="get"` for this. The problem here is, I need a refreshable and shareable URL for the queries. Please note, paginating should also be possible. I was thinking about something like this: `mydomain.com/3/?query=t-shirt+XL+red

EDIT

My Controller

```
$form = $this->createForm(new SearchType());
```

My FormType (SearchType)

```
    $builder
        ->setMethod('GET')
        ->add('query', 'text')
        ->add('save' , 'submit')
        ->getForm();
```

The code  above does almost what I want. It generates a "GET"-URL like:

```
search?query=hakro&save=&_token=KgCx2xOEphSMcIXr7OyFjkG87W6xizsaXT-0WLeUch0
```

But I don't want "save" and "token" parameters. How do I get rid of them?

Comment: Erm, ok, that right there is quite doable. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I know, it seems so trivial but I am hitting a wall in this case..
I tried to change the method in the FormType (not working because of generateURL) and in my controller (not working, no error message)

`$builder
                   ->setAction($this->generateUrl('orth_index_search'),          array('slug' => 'string'))
            ->setMethod('GET')`

Comment: Try adding some more code to your question....

Comment: Please share some code, what you've tried so far and where you're stuck ... the question is too generic otherwise.

Comment: I shared some more code now..